# Replacement matching regex with anchor tag?

Tags: regex, html, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I have a problem when using Regex. I have a html document which create an anchor link when it matches condition.

An example html:

> Căn cứ Luật Tổ chức HĐND và UBND ngày 26/11/2003;
>
> Căn cứ Nghị định số **63/2010/NĐ-CP** ngày 08/6/2010 của Chính phủ về
>   kiểm soát thủ tục hành chính;
>
> Căn cứ Quyết định số **165/2011/QĐ-UBND** ngày 06/5/2011 của UBND tỉnh
>   ban hành Quy định kiểm soát thủ tục hành chính trên địa bàn tỉnh;
>
> Căn cứ Quyết định số **278/2011/QĐ-UBND** ngày 02/8/2011 của UBND tỉnh
>   ban hành Quy chế phối hợp thực hiện thống kê, công bố, công khai thủ
>   tục hành chính và tiếp nhận, xử lý phản ánh, kiến nghị của cá nhân, tổ
>   chức về quy định hành chính trên địa bàn tỉnh;
>
> Xét đề nghị của Giám đốc Sở Công Thương tại Tờ trình số
>   **304/TTr-SCT** ngày 29 tháng 5 năm 2013

I want to match these bold texts and make anchor links from these. If it has, try ignore. Link example `<a href="/tags?query=63/2010/NĐ-CP">63/2010/NĐ-CP</a>`

```
var matchLegals = new Regex(@"(?:[\d]+\/?)\d+\/[a-z\dA-Z_ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ\-]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

                var allElements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='main-content']").Descendants();
            foreach (var node in allElements)
            {
                var matches = matchLegals.Matches(node.InnerHtml);

                foreach (Match m in matches)
                {
                    var k = m.Value;
                   //dont know what to do
                }

            }
```

What can i do this
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shaamaan thank for your advice. After few hours of coding, it works now

```
var content =    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='main-content']");
var items = content.SelectNodes(".//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']");
foreach (HtmlNode node in items)
 {
       if (!matchLegals.IsMatch(node.InnerText) || node.ParentNode.Name == "a")
{
                               continue;
 }

  var texts = node.InnerHtml.Trim();
  node.InnerHtml = matchLegals.Replace(texts, a => string.Format("<a href='/search?q={0}'>{0}</a>",a.Value));

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your regex pattern is OK and works. Another assumption is that `node.InnerHtml` doesn't contain any `<a>` tags already encompassing any of the potential matches.

In this case, it's as simple as doing something like this:

```
node.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml, "[your pattern here]", "<a href='query=$&'>$&</a>");

...

doc.Save("output.html");
```

Note, that you may need to work on the `href` component - I'm unsure how your link should be built.

Comment: Everything works fine when the first run. It causes error of nested anchor elements <a href=''><a>sample regex</a></a> and i have no idea about that

Comment: @tuan.it89 Sounds like you're running the code multiple times for the same segment. Try a step-by-step debugger and make sure the `Regex.Replace` isn't done more than once per HTML segment. Also, the code assumes that the matches in your HTML don't already have <a> tags around them!

Comment: Users need to update article content several times, so this will re-match content again. I need to find a way to regex a new matches and ignore exists.

Comment: @tuan.it89 In this case this is a different problem. You asked how to add `<a>` tags, and my answer provides that information. Now you need to use HtmlAgility to go through various HTML nodes and only process those nodes which are purely text (no inner HTML code).

Answer (score 1):

you match text and replace:

```
<script>

    var s = '...';
    var matchs = s.match(/\d{2,3}\/\d{4}\/[a-zA-Z\-áàảãạăâắằấầặẵẫậéèẻẽẹêếềểễệóòỏõọôốồổỗộơớờởỡợíìỉĩịđùúủũụưứửữựÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼÊỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỨỪỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỵỷỹ]+/gi);
    if (matchs != null) {
        for(var i=0; i<matchs.length;i++){
            var val = matchs[i];
            s = s.replace(val, '<a href="?key=' + val + '"/>' + val + '</a>');
        }
    }
    document.write(s);

</script>
```